# Methods of template class and enable_if

Tags: c++, templates

I need some ways to use only specific types when declaring the method of a template class.

Evenitally, I found out the std::enable_if class. But I only managed to use it to implemetations of whole classes and external functions and cannot find out how to use it for template class methods.

I want to manage to do somthing similar to this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class C {
    public:
        template <typename Enable = void> void foo();
};

template <typename T>
template <typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral_v<T>>::type>
void C<T>::foo() {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    C<float> A;
    C<int> B;
    
    A.foo(); // Error
    B.foo(); // Output: test

    return 0;
}
```

This code is not compiling, because the compiler cannot find the declaration of `C<T>::foo()`.